# Tomcat 8.5 and contextConfig can't initialize

Tags: java, tomcat8

I'm running a java application with tomcat 7 (7.0.42) on ubuntu 18 with java 8, I just upgraded my tomcat to tomcat 8.5.30 but an error keep stopping the the proper functioning of my app.
The server keep running but don't load the web page.

My error :

```
    09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.099 INFO [main]  org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.177 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '1' did not find a matching property.
09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.271 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.280 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.282 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 433 ms
09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.318 INFO [main] com.mchange.v2.log.MLog.<clinit> MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.340 INFO [main] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry.banner Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.378 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Démarrage du service Catalina
09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.378 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.496 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer The ServletContentInitializer [# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more] could not be created
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

as you can see with

```
09-Jul-2018 14:17:04.378 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

it may be caused by an error of version
here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
            id="WebApp_ID" 
            version="2.5">

    <display-name>osiris-web</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>softwareName</param-name>
        <param-value>OSIRIS</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/pages/home.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>osirisGuiServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>osirisGuiServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/osirisGui</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
        <param-value>/faces/pages/diva/diva.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.airbus.osiris.generic.utils.constant.WebConstantsInitializer</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.eurocopter.osiris.utils.webapp.jsf.ApplicationConstantsInitializer</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.eurocopter.osiris.utils.listener.OsirisSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.maxRequestSize</param-name>
        <param-value>200000000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>ServletSystemProperties</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ServletSystemProperties</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.eurocopter.osiris.utils.system.servlet.ServletSystemProperties</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletSystemProperties</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/systemProperties</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.richfaces.webapp.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/__richfaces_push</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.push.handlerMapping</param-name>
        <param-value>/__richfaces_push</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <display-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.eurocopter.osiris.utils.filter.SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionTimeoutFilter</filter-name>     
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Check database connection -->
    <filter>
        <display-name>DatabaseUnvailableFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>DatabaseUnvailableFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.eurocopter.osiris.utils.filter.DatabaseUnvailableFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>DatabaseUnvailableFilter</filter-name>     
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

when you search this problem you find this : https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55210
but I don't know whether the patch was applied or not or how to do it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You say you upgraded to tomcat 8.5, but the logs indicate you are still running 7, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

One change in tomcat 8 was that they updated the supported servlet version to 3.1, but you are still running 2.5:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" 
version="2.5">
```

My tomcat8 server is configured to 3.1 like so:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">
```

You can find more information about migrating from tomcat 7 to tomcat 8 [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html#Migrating_from_7.0.x_to_8.0.x) and to 8.5 [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html).